# Automated testing for mobile applications

Tags: automated-testing, mobile, android, ios

I am looking for an application like selenium but for mobile devices such as android/IOS would anyone have any applications that would suit this description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Appium? I haven't used it but I think it's pretty much selenium for native app testing.

http://appium.io/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are looking for tool similar to Selenium for mobile application testing, then you should go for **'Selendroid'**

Refer   http://selendroid.io/

**Selendroid** is a test automation framework fully compatible with Selenium, that's why it is called as 'Selenium for Android'. It can be used on emulators and real devices and can be integrated as a node into the Selenium Grid for scaling and parallel testing.

You can also use the same for iOS mobile application testing with its iOS driver

http://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/

If you are interested in paid tools then you can also try

1. Test Complete    http://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/mobile-module/overview/
2. Test Studio http://www.telerik.com/teststudio
3. ExperiTest (supports even Blackberry and Windows)     https://experitest.com/automation/
4. Saucelabs   https://saucelabs.com/

Answer (score 0):

I up-voted GKS1's answer because I have used Appium and it's great, once you get it setup.

I will also recommend [Telerik Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/teststudio) if you have the funding. It currently only supports iOS but Andorid is coming soon. A major benefit is that it uses physical machines rather than the XCode iOS Simulator. I have found minor differences in emulated devices compared to physical ones.